# After tracking data to blender 2.8 script

Tags: camera

Where can I find a script to export camera tracking data from after effects to blender 2.8.

Comment: Not to be rude, but have you tried googling "after effects tracking data blender"?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried googling it, but with little success, I’ve found quite a few scripts and plugins that work with older version blender, but none that work with 2.8. I’ve tried a few with the older versions and then saving and opening in 2.8 but that also doesn’t work :(

Comment: AE2blend appears to support 2.8 https://blendermarket.com/products/ae2blend not sure if this does what you are looking for?